# How to resolve port directions in a module instance tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, language-agnostic

In electrical engineering, we often deal with a hierarchy of module instances which can be represented as a tree where every tree node is an instance of a module.  These modules are connected by signals which can be outputs, inputs or inouts (bi-directional drive direction). In general, the following rules apply:

1. Each node can have zero or more sub-nodes (children).
2. Each node can have one or more ports which connect them to other node(s) in the tree.
3. Each port can have one of three (drive) directions: input (from node to child), output (from child to node) and inout (both ways).

Given a tree with leaf nodes along with their port directions, I have been looking for a simple algorithm to resolve the intermediary port directions, i.e. the goal is to know the port directions of all nodes in the tree connecting the given leaf nodes.

Filtering the tree by signal simplifies the problem such that a given tree is a subset of the original tree with all except one signal removed. This changes rule 2 to

2. Each node (of the filtered tree) has exactly one port which connects it to all other nodes of the tree.

As for the rules to propagate directions:

1. If all children have the same direction, the current node's is the same
2. If there's at least one child which is inout *or* there's at least one with input and one with output, it depends on other nodes which direction the current node will get (this is where it gets tricky).

Using the notation `<X` (node X is an output node), `>Y` (node Y is an input node) and `<>Z` (Z is a bidir node), here are some examples:

#### 1:

```
  B-<D           <B-<D
 /              /
A       ==>    A
 \              \
  C->E           >C->E
```

#### 2:

```
  <B                <B
 /                 / 
A                 A  
 \   >D            \    >D
  \ /      ==>      \  /
   C->E              >C->E
    \                  \
     >F                 >F
```

#### 3:

```
     <D                    <D
    /                     /  
   B                   <>B   
  / \                 /   \  
 /   >E              /     >E
A           ==>     A     
 \     <G            \         <G
  \   /               \       /  
   C-F->H              <>C-<>F->H 
      \                       \  
       >I                      >I
```

#### 4:

```
     <D                   <D
    /                    /  
   B                   <B   
  / \                 /  \  
 /   >E              /    >E
A           ==>     A     
 \                   \    
  C->F                >C->F
```

#### 5:

```
     <D                   <D
    /                    /  
   B                   >B   
  / \                 /  \  
 /   >E              /    >E
A           ==>     A     
 \                   \    
  C-<F                <C-<F
```

I think the algorithm will probably start at the leaves and propagate towards the root (`A`), applying propagation rule 1 above. If we hit a rule 2 case (such as in example 3 nodes `B`, `F` and, possibly later, `C`), I'm currently unsure how to proceed further, maybe keep propagating other nodes until (when?) it is determined which direction the current node will be?

#### Edit 2019-08-14

As commenters have asked about which rules apply when resolving directions in some of the examples, here they are (I hope that covers all cases):

1. As mentioned above, if all children of a node have the same direction, the parent inherits it (see examples 1, 2 C, 4 C and 5 C).
2. If the children of a node have mixed directions, it depends:

   1. If there are other nodes with mixed directions (such as between 3 B and 3 F), the nodes will have inouts.
   2. If all other nodes have a single direction (as in examples 4 and 5, between nodes B and F), that determines the port direction of the node with the children of mixed directions.

Comment: I do not understand your logic. e.g. what about node A? In scenario 5 B is an inport, based on what?

Comment: @Aldert To keep it simple, I left out the possibility of A having ports. Regarding 5 B, this is because there are no other input nodes in any of the A descendants *other than B*.

Comment: In example 5, B has two children, D and E; D has an output, E has an input, so B should be bidirectional. Or are there more rules than those you've mentioned so far?

Comment: @m69 I have edited the question to list the rules I'm aware of explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll traverse the tree from left to right, and a limited number of nodes may have to be visited a second time. In every node, we'll store its status: input, output, bidirectional, or to be determined. Consider this example:

```
           --  A  --
         /           \
       B               C
     /   \           /   \
   D       E      >F      >G
  / \     / \
>H  >I   J>  K>
```

We traverse to the leftmost leaf H, find that it is an input, move up to its parent D again, and provisionally mark D as an input. Then we look at the other child I, which is also an input, we move up to D again, and mark it provisionally as an input again. We then notice that D has no more children, and was marked only as an input, so we can mark it permanently as an input.

All of D's children of which the status could be determined will not have to be visited again, so we can ignore them from now on. So now we have:

```
           --  A  --
         /           \
       B               C
     /   \           /   \
  >D       E      >F      >G
          / \
         J>  K>
```

We move up to B, and provisonally mark it as an input, and then go on to visit its other child E. Similarly as with D, we find that E's status can be determined as an output, and that its children J and K will not have to be visited again:

```
           --  A  --
         /           \
       B               C
     /   \           /   \
  >D       E>     >F      >G
```

We move up to B again, and provisionally mark it as an output; it is now marked as both input and output, so we change its status to "to be determined". D and E will not have to be visited again. So now we have:

```
           --  A  --
         /           \
      ?B?              C
                     /   \
                  >F      >G
```

We move up to A, set its status provisonally to "to be determined", because it has a yet to be determined child, and then move down to the next node F. After examining F and G we find that C is an input, so we get:

```
           -- ?A? --
         /           \
      ?B?             >C
```

We move back up to A and find that we have visited all of its children, and that it has one undetermined child, and all other children are inputs. That means that the undetermined child becomes an output. We then propagate B's status as an output to any children it might have that also have an undetermined status (in the example there are none). This downward propagation means that in the worst case, the whole tree is traversed twice.

```
           -- ?A? --
         /           \
       B>             >C
```

*There is some uncertainty here. If A had three children: one input, one output, and one to be determined, you have not yet defined a rule for what would happen to the to be determined child.*

---

Let's look at another example:

```
           --  A  --
         /           \
       B               C
     /   \           /   \
   D       E       F>     >G
  / \     / \
>H   I>  J> >K
```

We find that B has two children that are both to be determined:

```
           --  A  --
         /           \
      ?B?              C
     /   \           /   \
  ?D?     ?E?      F>     >G
```

So we make B bidirectional and propagate this to its to be determined offspring, to end up with:

```
           --  A  --
         /           \
      >B>              C
                     /   \
                   F>     >G
```

If I understand the rules correctly, this bidirectional status is then propagated to every undetermined node in the rest of the tree, without the need for additional traversal:

```
           --  A  --
         /           \
      >B>             >C>
```

---

So the algorithm is:

- Visit every node, starting from the root node
- If the node is a leaf, remember its status, move up to its parent, and give the parent that status provisionally.
- If you have visited every child of a node, look at its provisional status: if only input or output has been marked, then the node becomes an input or an output. If both input and output have been marked, then it becomes to be determined. If more than one child had status to be determined, the node becomes bidirectional, and this is propagated down to all its undetermined offspring. We then carry this status up to its parent provisionally.
- Once we have set the status of any node to bidirectional, every undetermined node in the tree becomes bidirectional (if I understand the rules correctly).

---

Practical details:

How a child's status is remembered when you move up to the parent can be done is several ways. You can store boolean flags for input and output, and a count for undetermined (so that you know whether there's more than one), and possibly a seperate boolean flag for bidirectional (in case having a bidirectional child influences the parent in a different way than having a mix of input and output children). But you could also not store the states in the parent node, and look at the children's states again once you find that you've visited all the children.

A node's own status only has 4 states: input, output, bidirectional and undetermined, so that could be stored with just two booleans, where both false means undetermined.

You could store information in each node about which children have to be visited when a status is propagated down to undetermined nodes, but that again isn't strictly necessary; you can just look at the status of each child to update the undetermined ones. Only an undetermined node can have undetermined offspring, so you know that you don't have to visit the children of nodes that weren't undetermined.

The rule you mention in a comment, where a node with three children that are input, output and undetermined would mean the undetermined child becomes bidirectional, is indeed an additional rule. But at the point where you've visited all of a node's children, the details of how you combine the children's states into the parent's status can be easily modified to include any additional rule. If you decide that the undetermined child must become bidirectional, you'd then propagate this status to undetermined offspring of the child, and (if I understand the rules correctly) from that point on every undetermined node you find in the rest of the tree would automatically become bidirectional.

Comment: Nice work, thanks! As for the uncertainty, a node with three children (one undetermined, one input, one output), the undetermined one would have to become a bidirectional one. Would this mean adding a special case to your algorithm or would this work as-is?

Comment: @FriendFX I updated the answer with some practical details, and also addressed your comment.